# Setting the title of a dynamic view from a table view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I'm using a combination of SWRevealViewController, A ContentViewController and A NavigationViewController (Navigation).

The storyboard is as follows:

[image: current status of the storyboard]

On TableViewCell click I can get the navigation text. What I want to be able to do is to pass this information back into itself. Setting the title of the ContentViewController to the selected cell and loading other desired data.

How can I fulfil this functionality?

Here is my latest code within my NavigationViewController.m file:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BOOL isChild = currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex && indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];


    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (isChild) {
        NSString *cellText = selectedCell.detailTextLabel.text;
        NSLog(@"%@ tapped",cellText);
        return;
    }
    else{
        NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
        NSLog(@"%@ tapped",cellText);

        if([cellText isEqualToString:@"Sign Out"]){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToHome" sender:self];
        }
        else if ([cellText isEqualToString:@"Sign In"]){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToHome" sender:self];
        }
        else if ([cellText isEqualToString:@"Festival Map"]){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"festivalMap" sender:self];
        }
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if (currentExpandedIndex == indexPath.row) {
        [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
        currentExpandedIndex = -1;
    }
    else {

        BOOL shouldCollapse = currentExpandedIndex > -1;

        if (shouldCollapse) {
            [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
        }

        currentExpandedIndex = (shouldCollapse && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : indexPath.row;

        [self expandItemAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}



- (void)expandItemAtIndex:(int)index {
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray *currentSubItems = [subItems objectAtIndex:index];
    int insertPos = index + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < [currentSubItems count]; i++) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertPos++ inSection:0]];
    }
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

- (void)collapseSubItemsAtIndex:(int)index {
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = index + 1; i <= index + [[subItems objectAtIndex:index] count]; i++) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"festivalMap"]){
        NSLog(@"TEST");

        NSString * title = @"CHANGE";

        ViewController * view = [segue destinationViewController];
        view.navigationItem.title = title;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for my ContentViewController.m file:

```
#import "ContentViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "Function.h"

@interface ContentViewController ()

@end

@implementation ContentViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}

@end
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the data you trying to pass

Comment: just theselectedCell.textLabel.text I get from within didSelectRowAtIndexPath and pass it to the ContentViewController

Comment: You can get your selected cell with `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];`

Comment: I've already done that... it's passing the data that is the problem and loading it in the ContentViewController

Comment: Setting `segue.destinationViewController.title` in `prepareForSegue:sender:` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yoursegue"]){  
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ContentViewController*contentView = (ContentViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    contentView.cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text; 
    NSLog(@"cellText  = %@",selectedCell.textLabel.text;);
  }
}
```

However, it is not good practice to access value from the user interface or build the logic around it, instead you should be using the datasource.This violate MVC principles.

Comment: Can you ellaborate on the violation of MVC principles? What can I do to follow the guidelines?

Comment: Plus this solution does not work! I've added :`@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString * viewTitle;` to my ContentViewController.h file and `_viewTitle = self.title` in ContentViewController.m file is that right?

Comment: @Chris As an alternative you can also declare `cellText` on the class level like a property then access the value in the segue. Did you get anything int the logs

Comment: no.. the app runs. but the Title of the navigation bar title does not change

Comment: @Chris declare `NSString *cellText`  on teh class level and then use `NSLog` in both places to see the value

Comment: if you look at the storyboard.. am I passing the right data to the right controller? It keeps throwing an error :( The error being: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SWRevealViewController setMyTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd96ad4e150'`